# Capture video from webcam in safari

Tags: macos, safari, webrtc, getusermedia

Is it possible to capture video stream in Safari (OS X) with native API without using any external plugins (flash, silverlight, etc...)? Is there an analog of chrome/firefox 'navigator.getUserMedia'?

Answer (score 2):

getUserMedia is currently not supported in Safari ([source](http://caniuse.com/stream).) IE is also a laggard in this regard. So to answer your question, you will need to use a plugin or fallback.